# NServiceBus Delay Retries configure on only one queue

Tags: rabbitmq, azureservicebus, nservicebus

I have an instance of NServiceBus that is used for multiple queues. Now I have only one queue that requires a special type of delay retries and a custom policy. In this queue I have a 3rd party call, and I want it to be retried 10 times with a specific pattern of time interval.

I have read the [documentation about delayed retries](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/recoverability/configure-delayed-retries), my understanding is that it will affect all the queues, not only the one I want.
How this can be implemented?

I'm using NServiceBus with RabbitMq for testing envs and Azure Service Bus for prod envs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recoverability policy is applied on the endpoint level. When you need a certain message type to be processed with a different recoverability policy, you can [override](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/recoverability/custom-recoverability-policy#implement-a-custom-policy-full-customization) the default recoverability policy to customize it to your needs. When you need a completely different number of delayed retries configured that does not match the rest of the messages, you should split the logical endpoint into two and have the message type that requires a different recoverability handled by the new endpoint.